# How to identify reused widgets in ListViews

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-listview, android-preferences

I have what I consider to be a strange dilemma, although YMMV.

I'm using a layout file that describes each line/row in a ListView (nothing too exotic about that). I have an id assigned to each one, such as:

android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
android:id="@+id/contactLabel" // a TextView

Now this doesn't seem to make sense, as these ids should be unique, so what is the id of the second 
row? That is, if "row 1" honors the specified ids of checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, and contactLabel, what would the "row 2" ids be?

I'm curious, but also I need to know because I want to save the values of the checkboxes to a SharedPreferences object.

Who has a clue about how to get around this?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Update

The first thing I need to solve is how to respond to a click on the ListView. This is my current conundrum related to all of this:

**ListView doesn't know it's been clicked, or won't tell me**

I've added this event handler to my ListActivity:

```
  @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

...but it's not getting called. I click on the Contacts that display, but no go.

I also tried it this way:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    }
});
```

...still no joy...I put breakpoints on both "Toast" lines, and they never get reached.

I read here:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listsactivity_layout

...that, "In case you need more the just a ListView in your Activity, you can use you own layout for 
ListActivity."

...which I do, because I add a header and a footer in addition to the listview.

It goes on to say, "In this case your layout must have an ListView element with the android:id 
attribute set to @android:id/list."

So I added this to my layout:

...but it makes no difference one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID's for the items within the `ListView` widget are referenced through their parent view when you inflate it in your `getView()` method.

To elaborate, you would have something like this is you `ListView` adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);
            }
```

Nown, a new view instance exists as the convertView. You can access your widgets using `covertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)`, `convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2)`, etc.

Each of these views is a child of your `ListView`. You can reference each individual view from your `ListView` using the `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()` methods from the `ListView` object.
However, since it is recommended to use the `convertView` view to recycle views, in that case you will only have reference to the views on screen at a time.

Also, with regards to the `SharedPreferences`, all the views in your `ListView` are populated by an `Adapter` subclass which would be the actual object that puts the values in the `Checkbox` and `TextView` widgets. This `Adapter` has a dataset that you provide it. Why not reference the values from the dataset directly, instead of trying to find them from the list items which are populated from the dataset in any case ? You can write to the dataset from the `ListView` when someone clicks a `CheckBox` so you have an easy ordered reference to all the items in the `ListView`.

---

**UPDATE: Added dummy source code**

OK. Let's start with a hypothical list. We want to display say five items on the list. For simplicity, I'll assume each has a `TextView` and a `Checkbox`. So my container class is:

```
class Item {
    String textView;
    boolean checked;
}
```

Now in my `Activity` where I want to display this list, I put an `ArrayList` of items (you can use just about any datastructure) as a class variable. Then I get the ListView reference and assign it an adapter.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Item> listItems;
    .....
    onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        .....
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); // this will be you list view
        MyAdapter listAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        ....
        // Rest of your Activity
        ....
        MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            int getItemCount() {
                return listItems.size();
            }

            Item getItem(int position) {
                return listItems.get(position);
            }

            View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // Here's the important part
                Item currentItem = listItems.getItem(position); // Since the array is a class variable, you can do either get or getItem

                ..... // do the standard individual item inflating ....

                checkbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                checkbox.OnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() { // or whatever listener there should be... I didn't check
                    ... // do whatever...
                    currentItem.setChecked(true);
            }
```

When you want to retrieve what items were clicked, just iterate through the Item class and find which ones are true or you perform whatever action you want within the `Listener` since you have a reference identifying individual members of the ListView dataset (here listItems ArrayList).

Apologies for any errors. Didn't do any checking.

Comment: Thanks; would you happen to have some sample code showing this available?

Comment: Nah... but I'd be happy to look over your implementation if you have problems

Comment: I"m not sure (actually, I have barely a clue) what you mean re: referencing the vals from the dataset. Once everything from Contacts has been loaded, is there a way to deduce which Contact is associated with my checkboxes?